# Proving Equivalence of Complex and Real Continuous Linear Functionals in a Complex Normed Space"

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am working on a proof regarding the equivalence of complex continuous linear functionals $f$ and the existence of a unique real continuous linear functional $u$ in a complex normed linear space $X$. Here's what I have so far:

**Forward Implication**:

I showed that if $f$ is continuous, it is bounded, and thus, $u$ is bounded as well.
I then defined $u(x)$ as $\Re(f(x))$ and established that u is continuous, leading to the existence of a real continuous linear functional $u$ on $X$.

**Reverse Implication**:

I expressed $f(x)$ as $f(x) = u(x) - i\big(u(ix)\big)$.
I demonstrated that the functionals $u$ and $-i\big(u(ix)\big)$ are both continuous functions, leading to the continuity of $f(x)$.
I'm looking for guidance on how to complete this proof, especially the part where I define $k(x)$ and show that $\|k(x)\| \le \|x\|$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I'm sorry, but you cannot assume that people will just know what you are talking about. You have to explain it clearly. What is the exact result you are trying to prove? Don't give vague descriptions. Clearly state the theorem.